# How to pass a type into func

Tags: java

Here is the situation:

```
interface A{}//interface for entities
class B implements A{}//entity B 
class C implements A{}//entity C 

abstract class AR<E extends A>{}//generate list of E via a file,this will be done after the construct func.
class BR extends AR<B>{}
class CR extends AR<C>{}
```

Now I want to maintain:
`Map<String,List<A>> data;//<filepath+filename, list of entities in file>`

The func. blow will return the list based on the fileAddr:

```
<E extends A,R extends AR<E>> List<A> getList(String fileAddr)
{
 if(data.containsKey(fileAddr))
  return data.get(fileAddr);
 else
 {
  AR<E> reader=new R(fileAddr);//generate a list of E via this file
  List<E> values=reader.getValues();
  data.put(fileAddr,values);
  return values;
 }
}
```

But this doesn't work,and `new R(fileAddr)` is not supported.

So how to implement getList() func. based the spec. above.

Comment: is 'E' being passed to this Class through the class' declaration?

Comment: you can't using the 'new' keyword for creating a Generic type: new R(...) in your case, is illegal in Java.

Comment: getList is a generic method,E is passed as a generic type for getList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `new` to generate an instance of a type parameter.  The technical reason is that the type information has been erased by the time that `getList` is executed.  Anyway, the Java language does not permit it.

One way around the problem is to pass in a factory object that can create the required instance.

Another way around it is to pass the parameter type's `Class` object as an argument, and then create the instance reflectively; e.g. something like this:

```
<E extends A,R extends AR<E>> List<A> getList(String fileAddr, Class<R> rClass)
{
 if(data.containsKey(fileAddr))
  return data.get(fileAddr);
 else
 {
  Constructor<R> ctor = rClass.getConstructor(String.class);
  R reader=ctor.newInstance(fileAddr);
  List<E> values=reader.getValues();
  data.put(fileAddr,values);
  return values;
 }
}
```

(There will be a bunch of exceptions to deal with ...)

Answer (score 0):

That line should be replaced with an actual Class, for example:

```
AR<E> reader=new BR(fileAddr); //or AR<B>
```

or:

```
AR<E> reader=new CR(fileAddr); //or AR<C>
```